# What is the amount of mass ($\rm kg$) that the Sun loses daily in the irradiation form?

Tags: astrophysics, mass-energy, estimation, sun

I had difficulties to post my question because the system asks me to detail my need more.

Is it necessary?

Doesn't my question make sense?

There is no need to answer, I just want to know if there is an answer to the title question.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want to know the mass flow that is equivalent to the energy of the light emitted by the sun.  I won't do the calculation for you (it is easy), but here is the approach.  Look up the amount of light energy emitted by the sun, in joules per second.  Divide that value by the square of the speed  of light in meters per second. The result is the number of kilograms per second the sun loses in the form of light energy.  Note, though, that the sun also loses mass via the "solar wind", consisting of ions and atoms moving outward from the sun in excess of the sun's escape velocity.

Comment: I am 66 years old, I am not a student, and this is the first time I have met someone who refuses to answer easy questions. I didn't know that this site is dedicated only to difficult questions. Would you give this same answer to your grandfather?

Comment: The point is, this site isn't there to do people's homework for them, and the question reads pretty much like a "plug some numbers into $E = mc^2$" exercise.

Comment: Understand! I will not ask any more questions on this site.

Comment: @JoãoBosco Please don't be disappointed, is just that we get many students a day who only want an answer to homework, so we try to help them with concepts and misunderstandings rather than just complete answers to homework like questions .The 3rd paragraph  here should help answer your question; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun

Comment: @Adrian Howard - Thank you!